# Will siding with The BOS mess up my supply lines?

Tags: fallout-4

During one of the Brotherhood side quests I am supposed to get supplies from a settlement that belongs to the Minutemen and has supply lines to another settlement but when I do that, there is a message saying that this settlement now belongs to the Brotherhood of Steel.

Will I have to setup those supply lines again?

Comment: It sounds like you've already done it. Can you just check if the supply lines are still intact?

Comment: I quick saved, reloaded and walked away from the quest. I guess I can do it again but I was hoping someone had some input.

Comment: I would be surprised if you had to reestablish the supply lines, but I haven't actually tried this scenario. If you try it, please answer and let us know what you found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went and did the quest again but I forgot to grab screenshots. I could still build structures(defense turrets and walls) and I didn't have to re-establish my supply lines.

Comment: +1, Thanks for figuring that out. I can stop ignoring that mission now.

Answer (score 0):

I came to post that it does not affect your supply lines or the settlements at all (except maybe for its happiness) but then I stumbled upon [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3sqs5x/spoilers_settlements_minutemen_or_brotherhood_of/) and apparently some people say doing the quest DOES make you completely lose control over it.(i.e. You can't use the workshop or build, hence no more supply lines either I assume)

I don't know if it's a bug that settlements sometimes remain yours or not, but since the only time I did this quest I did NOT lose control of the settlement I can't say for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really an answer. The link is interesting, but it sounds like they can't decide what causes you to keep or lose control.