# What are all the differences between Minutemen versus Brotherhood of Steel being in control of a location?

Tags: fallout-4

*[Contains potential spoilers]*

As leader of the Minutemen, I already had control of a dozen settlements or so before I joined the Brotherhood of Steel.

I started a radiant quest for the Proctor to requisition supplies from one of my settlements.

When I went to my [Minuteman-controlled] settlement, I spoke to the indicated settler, and passed an easy persuade check to convince him to donate food to the BoS. (I also saved beforehand, and tried other methods, such as paying for food, with same results).

As soon as I made the deal, I received a notification: `The Brotherhood now controls this location.`

**Question:** What are all the differences between Minutemen versus BoS being in control of a location?

I googled around and did not find a definitive answer - just lots of speculation and confusion on Reddit and Steam forums. Some folks complain they cannot built/modify the settlement at this point, but I had zero problems giving orders or building/moving turrets/walls/furniture/whatever; however, I did not try this after returning to the Proctor, only immediately after making the deal.

I checked map on my pip-boy, and still see the supply lines and it appears that I still "own" the settlement. Since it's just a radiant quest I reloaded my game until I understand exactly what I'm getting into.

Comment: Related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245159/will-siding-with-the-bos-mess-up-my-supply-lines/245197 though it doesn't have a clear answer either. It is indeed quite confusing, I'm just staying away from it myself for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some of the settlements (Roughly just over half) can be turned into allies of the Brotherhood of Steel. These select settlements can also be turned into safe houses for the railroad if they aren't already allied with the minutemen or BOS.

In terms of gameplay the Brotherhood had better weapons and equipment than the minutemen. If you haven't destroyed the Prydwen, you are far more likely to encounter a BOS patrol in the commonwealth than a Minutemen one, meaning that if your settlement is attacked you have a small chance to encounter a patrol to help you out.

You may wonder about artillery support. It may be a bug but I am able to build artillery in any of my settlements no matter what affiliation. So long as you've done the castle quest you can build them.

Ultimately they are similar enough that it's a role-playing choice for each location.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the airport had people I can send to and build a settlement there.  So maybe that has something to do with it.  Build with the BoS or Minutemen...  In the end you can have enough settlements to max out with Minutemen and have BoS as a sub group.  Or send everyone to BoS maybe and say screw the Minutemen.  I bet the Minutemen will be pissed that you sent most to the BoS.
   The way I see it, who cares if you lose 1 settlement to the BoS, they need the food. Minutemen can't watch over everyone all the time.  I'll see how this plays out.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, the Q&A site for games! When answering someone's question, make sure to provide some form of verifiable proof or context. It seems the user is asking for the differences between two factions owning an area in a game. Unfortuneately, your answer to their question doesn't follow our Q&A format. I recommend you edit it to be somewhat more authoritative. Opinions are fine, so long as they address the question and not lead more or less to "Yeah, I've wondered that too."

Answer (score -1):

For me persuading the settlers to join the bos meant i was unable to issue commands in the settlements or use the workbench. This doesnt really answer the question but i massacred all the villagers and the town reverted to my control, so you can always do that if you have any issues

Comment: Were you a member of the BOS in good standing (not enemies) at the time?

Answer (score -1):

More speculation for you:

At the end of the game it is possible for things to come to a head in battle between the BoS and the Minutemen, depending on how you play out the game.

In short, it's possible that when relations between the factions breakdown that relations between the settlements may also breakdown. In other words, if you've fostered the transfer of allegiance from the Minutemen to the BoS, you should expect trade relations to break down between the settlements (cancellation of supply lines), and for your own relations to break down with the settlements who affiliate with the faction you ultimately decide to oppose.

Logically, that's how the system would conclude, if it is fleshed out to that degree, in my opinion.