# What settlements are available with no faction affiliation?

Tags: fallout-4

If my character does not do any faction quests, what settlements will be available to claim?

Bonus: If I later align with a particular faction by completing their quests, do the settlements I founded earlier become aligned with that faction too (or what happens if not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on everything I've read here and done in-game, settlements are *yours*, not any particular faction's.

As an example, [claiming a settlement for the Brotherhood of Steel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246058/108003) on one of Proctor Teagan's quests does *not* take it away from the Minutemen, does *not* interfere with your supply routes, and does *not* prevent you from using the workshop.

The only settlement I can think of which even *might* require a faction alignment to take is the Boston Airport.

Comment: I can speak from experience: the Boston Airport can have a supply line to, say Sanctuary and it will share all of your Minuteman settlement workshop resources, but you are probably right that you cannot claim it unless you are working for the brotherhood.

Comment: So, I helped Preston and friends set up shop at Sanctuary but declined when he asked me to lead the minutemen. Then I helped Abernathy Farm (entirely on my own initiative) and they told me they were joining the minutemen as a result (...they had nothing to do with it). I guess at this point the settlement belongs to me and not in fact the minutemen despite what he said? Is there a difference/does it matter?

Comment: @toucan I don't think I've actually declined Preston's offer before. You're probably the leader of the minutemen regardless of what you told him. If you can access the workbench, then the settlement is yours. Let us know.

Comment: I can access the workbench. I guess the dialog just threw me since I have yet to join the Minutemen and Blake told me explicitly he was joining them when I got workbench access. Preston doesn't become available to be your companion and doesn't give you any quests if you tell him no, and that's still where we stand, but I guess if all settlements work like Abernathy they just don't have dialog to account for me not being part of the Minutemen. The Abernathy quest also had the Minuteman symbol although they had nothing to do with it in my most recent playthrough.